# Bash script code explanation

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I am looking into the fast.ai course (deep learning for coders). One of their bash scripts to setup an instance in AWS, has this line of code that I am failing to understand (albeit knowing what it does):

[image]

I am quite certain, that this calls another bash script in the same directory. But there are six things I would like to understand/clarify:

1. Q1

   Why is there a . before $(dirname "$0")
2. Q2

   What is the difference between "$0" and $0, are you forcing the output in the fist case to be converted into a string?
3. Q3

   I checked what dirname "$0" does by echoing it into my command line. It looks like it gives the name of the shell? So in my case (using Cygwin and executing: `echo "$0"`), it prints "-bash" to the console.
4. Q4

   What does dirname do?
5. Q5

   What is the value of $(dirname "$0")?
6. Q6

   Will the variables: $region,$ami and $instanceType be transferred into setup_instance.sh, and why?

Comment: [BashGuide/Sourcing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Sourcing), [Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), [BashFAQ/028](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028), [`dirname` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dirname-invocation.html#dirname-invocation) are a few good reads.

Comment: 1: `type .` and `help .` 4: `type dirname` and `man dirname`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `.` is the original name for the `source` command. It executes a shell script in the current process.
2. Quoting a variable expands it as a single word and prevents wildcard expansion of the result. Most of the time you should quote variables when you're using them, unless you specifically need word splitting and globbing.
3. Inside a shell script, `$0` contains the pathname of the script. In an interactive shell it contains the pathname of the shell.
4. It outputs the directory portion of a pathname. `dirname foo/bar/baz` prints `foo/bar`.
5. Combine the answers to #3 and #4 -- it's the directory portion of the script's pathname. So this looks for the `setup_instance.sh` script in the same directory as this script.
6. Yes, they will, because `.` executes the commands in `setup_instance.sh` in the same shell process where these were assigned.

Comment: add 6. and because it is executed in the same shell, variables set within that script are still valid after the script has finished. Which would not be the case if called without the dot, thus called in a subshell.